# Send local notifications every day at 6 PM Swift 3 iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios9, localnotification

I"m trying to trigger local notifications in my application every day at 6 PM. this is the code I'm using, but for some odd reason, it doesn't want to fire at the specific time. what am i doing wrong?

```
func notify() {

    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)!
    var dateFire=NSDate()

    var fireComponents=calendar.components([.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from:NSDate() as Date)

    fireComponents.hour = 18
    fireComponents.minute = 0

    dateFire = calendar.date(from: fireComponents)! as NSDate

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Please take your tests for today! ❤️"
    notification.fireDate = fireDate // this always works NSDate().addingTimeInterval(0.0001) as Date
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day

    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

I also don't want to use the new UserNotifications framework from iOS 10 because i need to develop for a iOS 9.0 environment.